# How are OS patches with critical security update on GCE, GKE and AI Platform notebook?

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

Is there complete documentation that explains if and how critical security updates are applied to an OS image on the following IaaS/PaaS?

- GCE VM
- GKE (VM of in a cluster)
- VM on which is running AI Platorm notebook

In which cases is the GCP team taking care of these updates and in which cases should we take care of it?

For example, in the case of a GCE VM (Debian OS) the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images#debian) seems to indicate that no patches are applied at all and no reboots are done.

What are people doing to keep GCE or other VMs up to date with critical security updates, if this is not managed by GCP?  Will just restarting the VM do the trick?  Is there some special parameter to set in the YAML template of the VM? I guess for GKE or AI notebook instances, this is managed by GCP since this is PaaS, right? Are there some third party tools to do that?

Comment: For the first two services that you listed (GCE/GKE) YOU are responsible for patches and updates. I cannot answer the third. Patches and updates are a touchy topic. There are many opinions on how this should be done. My opinion is that nothing should be updated until tested and approved by following documented procedures. Your question - as worded - does not have an answer and can only generate opinions.

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley. I am looking for opinion since it highly depend of the context. What confuse me a bit is how to deploy such patches on GKE cluster for example. Somehow I need to check what OS version is running on the VM and then apply or not the patches. For a big cluster it maybe an not easy task. Is there tools to help in such task. I am a Data Scientsit not a Linux Engineer so I am probably missing the basics here,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As John mentioned, for the GCE Vm instances, you are responsible for all of the packages updates and it is handled like in any other System:

Linux: sudo apt/yum update/upgrade
Windows: Windows update

There are some internal tools in each GCE image that could help you to automatically update your system:

- Windows: automatic updates are enabled by default
- RedHat/Centos systems: you can use yum-cron tool to enable automatic updates
- Debian: using the tool unattended-upgrade

As per GKE, I think this is done when you upgrade your cluster version, the version of the master is upgraded automatically (since it is Google managed), but the nodes should be done by you. The node update can be automated, please see the second link below for more information.

Please check the following links for more details on how the Upgrade process works in GKE:

[Upgrading your cluster](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/upgrading-a-cluster)
[GKE Versioning and upgrades](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/versioning-and-upgrades#upgrades)

As per "VM on which is running AI Platform notebook", I don't understand what do you mean by this. Could you provide more details

Comment: Thanks @grimmjow-sms, thanks for these information.
For the AI Platform notebook, should I take care of the critical packages updates when the instance is running for few weeks ? This is special image for Machine Learning that are running on GCE instance. Below some doc in case I am using the wrong vocabulary:
https://cloud.google.com/deep-learning-vm/docs/
https://cloud.google.com/deep-learning-vm/docs/concepts-images

Comment: @Dr.FabienTarrade could you please let me know if this ML image was taken from the Market Place? If so, could you please provide the name and version, I might take a look and give you more details.

Comment: images are stored in container registry and here you can find some more info (I don't know if we can also get them from the Market Place):
https://cloud.google.com/deep-learning-vm/docs/images
You can also get the list with the command below
gcloud compute images list --project deeplearning-platform-release --no-standard-images

Comment: @Dr.FabienTarrade you are right, I think there is a lack of information in that link. You can send feedback directly to google team and ask for more details about any questions you have related to documentation. I already did from my end, maybe if you do it also, they might act faster.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. I will ask them as well.